# What does list index out of range mean in our code?

Tags: python

We are making a temperature sensor for our programming class in school and we have encountered problems with this particular line of code:

```
devicefile= devicelist[0] + '/w1_slave'
```

IndexError: list index out of range

We got our code from these websites:
http://www.whiskeytangohotel.com/2013/07/raspberry-pi-charting-ambient-vs.html
http://raspberrywebserver.com/gpio/connecting-a-temperature-sensor-to-gpio.html

Answer (score 3):

It means that the list `devicelist` has less than 1 element (`devicelist[0]` being the first element in the list). IOW : it's an empty list.

For more on lists in Python, refer to the tutorial http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists and the library references http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange

Comment: How can we fix our code to make there so there is no indexerror

Answer (score 1):

`IndexError` means you have tried to access something by index, but that index is outside the bounds of the container, e.g.

```
>>> l = [0, 1, 2]
>>> l[2]
2
>>> l[3]
...
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If a container does not have a zeroth element, it must be empty:

```
>>> l = []
>>> l[0]
...
IndexError: list index out of range
```

You need to investigate why the list is empty, but for more robust code you can check explicitly before trying to access the element:

```
if len(l) > 0:
    # access l[0]
```

or, simply:

```
if l:
    # access l[0]
```

Comment: How can we fix our code to make there no IndexError?